# Mdx Sum returns non integer value

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

When have a issue at work where the value returned by the SUM() function isn't treated like a "normal" number when using the value returned together with the Round() function.

Try this MDX for example

```
WITH 
MEMBER SomeNumber AS 0.595 
SET SomeNumberSet AS 
           {[SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber] }

MEMBER SomeNumberSum AS
Round(SUM([SomeNumberSet], [Measures].[SomeNumber]) / 8, 2)


SELECT [SomeNumberSum] ON 0

FROM [SomeCube]
```

This code returns 0.59, the sum of sets are 4,76, which are then divided by 8 = 0,595. Since MDX is using Bankers rounding this SHOULD be rounded to 0.60.

Just using Round(0,595) gives us the correct result.

Whats even more strange is that if we in the set only uses the SomeNumber 6 times or less and in the Round Function divide with the same multiplier we get 0.6 (which is correct)

Also, if I wrap the Sum() with the StrToValue() function, it works, even if I use more than 5 SomeNumbers in the set

Whats going on?!

Comment: That what we call a bug or a wrong documentation, happens even to MS :-)

Comment: MEMBER SomeNumberSum AS round(0.595,2) is enough

Comment: Yes, Round(0.595,2) returns the correct result :)
But when in a set with over X items, divided by X, it returns the wrong value. (x > 5)

Comment: ok, so it's a problem of strictly <5 or >=5. Is this not a 'classical' issue with double ? -> you've always some rounding, precision issues, you've probably something like 5.949999999999999

Comment: icCube, not, If you round `somenumber` without sum the result is 0.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure is the actual answer you're looking for. The issue you've has to do with numerical precision, aka rounding errors, more than with MDX.

If you're in Java, run the following test :

```
public void testNumeric()
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double value = 0.595;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        sum += value;
    }

    double prod = value * 8;
    assertEquals(sum / 8, prod / 8);
}
```

The assert will fail, strange no ?

```
Result : expected:<0.5949999999999999> but was:<0.595>
```

The first one, sum, is how mdx is calculating the value. You got a slight difference, but it is enough for changing the result of the ROUND().

Is there a solution ?

Strictly speaking no, it's an error due to the very nature of the numeric calculation with computers. Practically you can cheat a bit round first to 10 - ROUND(ROUND(MyNumber,10),2), not brillant (10 is an example).

If you're interested start in wikipedia from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding_error)

Answer (score -1):

According with Chris Webb, this behaviour is intentional:

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/round.php

If you have Excel libraries, this works:

```
WITH 
MEMBER SomeNumber AS 0.595 
SET SomeNumberSet AS 
           {[SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber], [SomeNumber] }

MEMBER SomeNumberSum AS
Excel!Round(SUM([SomeNumberSet], [Measures].[SomeNumber]) / 8, 2)

SELECT [SomeNumberSum] ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: In that article they discuss Bankers rounding which should round it up, not round it down.

Comment: 0.595 should be rounded to 0.6 like i wrote in my question.

Comment: You can review the reply from Chris Webb here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/3133ef66-4529-466c-bfa4-db733eff3917/